# regex to find a letter but not the same letter if followed by another specific letter

Tags: regex, notepad++

I use NP++ and looking to find the letter 'a' in any word, but not if it is followed by 'b' (not if it is ab).

So it finds the a in such words:

```
and
back
spa
abbreviate (finds the second a here)
```

but doesn't find the a in such words:

```
abbey
enable
```

Comment: Are you just trying to find the "a" or do you want to match the entire word that contains it?

Comment: just any "a", if not "ab"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative lookahead assertion:

```
a(?!b)
```

This matches `a` that is not followed by `b`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks..  Do you happen to know also the negative lookahead assertion in FrontPage regex?

Comment: @Mike, I don't know about FrontPage regex.

Comment: @Mike, In [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/frontpage-help/regular-expressions-HP003092324.aspx), no mention about lookahead/lookbehind. It may not be the exaustive documentation. Please research yourself.